# curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate

Tags: linux, curl

When i send a curl inside a Linux server to check the connection to another domain, triggering below error.

`curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.`

It was working earlier and happened intermittently
 `curl -X POST https://console.idid.preprod.group/parse-sample-event/json`

Comment: What's not clear about the error?  What domain name are you using, and what does the certificate say?